# Wicked PDF fails on production only, PDF could not be generated!: could not find rake 13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rake, wicked-pdf

I've been searching all over the internet but couldn't find a working solution.

I have a rails app running on puma and nginx which generates a PDF with no problems on development (Mac OS Monterrey) but in production (Ubuntu 20.04) I'm getting this error:

```
[4ed5fc46-6ee0-46aa-863d-3cfd79689dd8] RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
["/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--enable-local-file-access", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20220504-24703-1gzck1m.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20220504-24703-1b64d4x.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
):
[4ed5fc46-6ee0-46aa-863d-3cfd79689dd8]   
[4ed5fc46-6ee0-46aa-863d-3cfd79689dd8] app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:121:in `block in update'
[4ed5fc46-6ee0-46aa-863d-3cfd79689dd8] app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:115:in `update'
```

Software versions:
rake-13.0.6 is installed, Wicked_pdf version is 2.6.0, wkhtmltopdf-binary version is 0.12.6.5., Rails version is 6.1.4, Ruby version is 2.6.5.

I'm using rvm, and already reinstalled ruby with same results.

If I run this code in the rails console on the server in production mode it works fine:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
```

But, if I run it on the controller like this the problem remains:

```
def update
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.update(sale_params)

        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
        save_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', "boleta_#{@sale.common_expense.folio}_#{@sale.common_expense.parcel.name.downcase}.pdf")
        
        File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
          file << pdf
          @sale.common_expense.file.attach(io: File.open(save_path), filename: "boleta_#{@sale.common_expense.folio}_#{@sale.common_expense.parcel.name.downcase}.pdf")
          @sale.common_expense.save!
          file.close
        end

        format.html { redirect_to(edit_sale_path(@sale), :notice => 'Venta actualizada.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @sale.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

My wicked_pdf initializer looks like this:

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  WickedPdf.config = {
    exe_path: '/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    enable_local_file_access: true
  }
end
```

Does anyone know what could be giving the error?

Thanks in advance!

**INFO UPDATE**

My app was updated from Rails 4.2.

I just installed on the same production server a new rails app with the basics to create a PDF file and it has no issues. I believe it has something to do with the rails update.

Comment: Finally it seems to be a Rails upgrade problem. I could not find a solution for this so I had to make a fresh start with my app in Rails 7, maybe I fail on something on the upgrade process.

Comment: I think what's happening here is the `exe_path` you are specifying is a binstub or shim rather than the actual binary. And that shim is written in Ruby and has a requirement for "rake". When the binstub is executed, it is using a different Ruby environment than the rest of your app. I would make sure to either point it at the absolute path to the actual binary, or make sure the correct RVM ruby environment is loaded for the processes that are spawned when you generate a PDF.